# Loading a local XML or Shapefile into OSMNX to create a graph

Tags: xml, anaconda, shapefile, geopandas, osmnx

How do you load a local file into OSMNX to create a graph?
We have a roadnetwork of a secret and private area that is not integrated in OSMNX, but we want to use the nice possibilities that OSMNX has.

I created from a shapefile a geodataframe with geopandas and if you have a geodataframe of the edges too you can use this function:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V9BF8.png)

But there has to be an easier way I think, I read also on a forum with this way some data will be less accurate and I want to provide a script that is reusable when they upgrade the roadnetwork again. So if somebody knows a way how to load a local xml or shapefile into OSMNX that would be great.

Kind regards,

Damiaan

Answer (score 0):

> So if somebody knows a way how to load a local xml or shapefile into OSMNX that would be great.

Per the OSMnx documentation, you can create a graph from a local .osm-formatted XML file with the [graph_from_xml](https://osmnx.readthedocs.io/en/stable/osmnx.html#osmnx.graph.graph_from_xml) function and you can create a graph from a shapefile with the [graph_from_gdfs](https://osmnx.readthedocs.io/en/stable/osmnx.html#osmnx.utils_graph.graph_from_gdfs) function (if you've loaded the shapefiles as node/edge GeoDataFrames first: see documentation for expected structure).

Comment: How do I get a XML file? I would want a XML for the whole world, but if that's too much, then a country.